# Python RE: how can I neglect empty space between tags?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have the following text:

```
<vehicle id="1292442" depart="26060.00">
      <route edges="24449167#2 27659684#1 24686876#1"/>
```

I would like to put the vehicle ID and each item in the route edges
in the tuples variable

```
tuples = re.findall(r'<vehicle\sid="(.+?)"\s+(<route\sedges="(.+)"/>', text)
```

how can I ignore the whitespace between tags?

```
 \s+
```

does not do this.

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is holy, don't [parse XML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/100297).

Comment: You can [use a library](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) for it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That should be the default response every time someone tries to do this.

Comment: @alandalusi does `<vehicle>` tag have many `<route>` tags or just 1? Also, how do you expect your result tuples to look like? Please update the question with extra details. Oh yeah, don't use `re` for XML parsing :) If this XML document is big, prefer `xml.sax` or some similar stream oriented parser, if this document isn't expected to be big, any XML parser will do.

Comment: @PavelRepin <vehicle> tag has just one <route> tag

Comment: @alandalusi Here's an example of doing it using a SAX parsing: https://gist.github.com/3948251

Comment: @PavelRepin Thanks, I wish you made a formal answer so that I can check

Comment: @alandalusi, I've just posted that thing as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stream-oriented XML parsing hack uses exclusively Python standard library.

Sorry for longish answer: since parsing XML is so mind-numbing that I prefer to find ways to do it "creatively" :)

The following code accumulates resulting tuples into a list. But since coroutines can be chained in arbitrary ways, you may evolve this into a more robust solution that lazily grabs vehicle tuples and processes them one by one or in chunks or whatever.

```
# Remixed from: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/cosax.py
# Don't shy away from reading http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/ if the stuff below
# seems weird.

from xml.sax import ContentHandler, parse
from collections import namedtuple

ElementStart = namedtuple('ElementStart', 'name attrs')
ElementEnd = namedtuple('ElementEnd', 'name')

class LazySax(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        self.target.send(ElementStart(name, attrs._attrs))
    def endElement(self, name):
        self.target.send(ElementEnd(name))

def pull_tuples(tuples):
    while True:
        event = yield
        if isinstance(event, ElementStart) and event.name == 'vehicle':
            vid = event.attrs['id']
            edges = None
            while True:
                event = yield
                if isinstance(event, ElementStart) and event.name == 'route':
                    edges = event.attrs['edges']
                elif isinstance(event, ElementEnd) and event.name == 'vehicle':
                    tuples.append((vid, edges))
                    break
```

Let's say you have `vehicles.xml` that has this:

```
<root>
 <foo />
 <bar>
  <!-- This block will be skipped. Try that with regex (please DON'T!).
  <vehicle id="1292441" depart="26060.00">
      <route edges="24449167#2 27659684#1 24686876#1"/>
  </vehicle>
  -->
  <vehicle id="1292442" depart="26060.00">
      <route edges="24449167#2 27659684#1 24686876#1"/>
  </vehicle>
 </bar>
 <vehicle id="1292443" depart="26060.00">
      <route edges="34449167#2 37659684#1 34686876#1"/>
 </vehicle>
 <vehicle id="1292444" depart="26060.00">
      <route edges="44449167#2 47659684#1 44686876#1"/>
 </vehicle>
</root>
```

Now if you do:

```
results = []
puller = pull_tuples(results); puller.next()
with open('vehicles.xml') as f:
    parse(f, LazySax(puller))
for result in results:
    print result
```

You'll see:

```
(u'1292442', u'24449167#2 27659684#1 24686876#1')
(u'1292443', u'34449167#2 37659684#1 34686876#1')
(u'1292444', u'44449167#2 47659684#1 44686876#1')
```

Which is what you want more or less. Just plain old XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

That's XML. You should be using an XML parser, not regular expressions.

That said, why not just `strip()` the excess white space afterward?

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/). That would give you easy access to the elements you want and their attributes. Regarding the different route edges in one attribute, use the `split()` method of strings:

```
In [1]: edges="24449167#2 27659684#1 24686876#1"

In [2]: edges.split()
Out[2]: ['24449167#2', '27659684#1', '24686876#1']
```